# Get specific element in webdriver containing text

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

What are some good ways to retrieve a specific element in WebDriver/Selenium2 based only on the text inside the element?

```
<div class="page">
  <ul id="list">
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Grape</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Essentially, I'd like to write something like this to retrieve the specific element:

```
@driver.find_element(:id, "list").find_element(:text, "Orange")
```

This is very similar to how I would use a selector when finding text inside a link (i.e. `:link_text` or `:partial_link_text`), but I would like to find elements by text inside normal, non-link elements.

Any suggestions? How do you deal with this issue? (In case you were wondering, I am using Ruby.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple years late, but I was just going to ask this question and answer it so other could find it...

I used a css selector to get all the li elements and then filtered the array based on the text:

```
@driver.find_elements(css: '#list > li').select {|el| el.text == 'Orange'}.first
```

You could then `.click` or `.send_keys :return` to select the option.

Answer (score 7):

You could do that with xPath. Something like this for your example:

```
@driver.find_element(:id, "list").find_element(:xpath, './/*[contains(., "Orange")]')
```

Comment: Thanks. Would prefer not to use xpath at all, but still, thanks for the great response!

Comment: Didn't know you could chain `find_element`, I'm assuming that it only searches the child elements of the first element... nice. ;)

Comment: Yeah, calling find_element on the driver starts at the root, while calling it on an element starts from that element. I think that the XPath could override that (so if the '.' wasn't at the start of the XPath, it might still start from the document root as directed by the //), but I don't remember for sure right now.